Include Exclude in one sql query output
MainAccountID is root of a tree which can have many Accounts and every account can have many City nodes and each child city node can have many cities.
There is a table ConfigFlow.tb, where every entry represents specific flow info, which needs to be created by using including and excluding City Ids
ConfigFlow.tb
MainAccountID,IncludeMainCityId,ExcludeMainCityId
1100,100,200
1200,200,300

AccountIds.tb
AccountId,MainAccountID
1,1100
2,1100
3,1200

CityIds.tb
CityId,MainCityId 
11,100
12,100
13,200
14,300

Inner Join ConfigFlow.tb with AccountIds.tb (on MainAccountID) to get all child account nodes and then inner joined with CityIds.tb to get all Cityids under IncludeMainCityId
Output only for IncludeMainCityId
1100,100,200,   1,1100,     11,100
1100,100,200,   2,1100,     12,100
1200,200,300,   3,1200,     13,200

Is there any way to write sql query to get output for both IncludeMainCityId,ExcludeMainCityId at once something like this ?
{ConfigFlow.tb}     {AccountIds.tb}     {IncludeCityIds}    {ExcludeCityIds}
1100,100,200,       1,1100,             11,100               0,0
1100,100,200,       2,1100,             12,100               0,0
1200,200,300,       3,1200,             13,200               0,0
1100,100,200,       1,1100,             0,0                  13,200
1200,200,300,       3,1200,             0,0,                 14,300 

Note: Not mentioned all columns names but mentioned the tables names (just to avoid writing so many columns in question, but every comma separation is a col of specific table mentioned)

You can JOIN the tables via the IncludeMainCityId and then use UNION ALL and JOIN the tables a second time via the ExcludeMainCityId:
SELECT cf.*,
       a.AccountId,
       ic.CityId AS IncludeCityId,
       ic.MainCityId AS IncludeMainCityId,
       0 AS ExcludeCityId,
       0 AS ExcludeMainCityId
FROM   configflow cf
       INNER JOIN accountids a
       ON cf.mainaccountid = a.mainaccountid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN cityids ic
       ON cf.IncludeMainCityId = ic.MainCityId
UNION ALL
SELECT cf.*,
       a.AccountId,
       0,
       0,
       ec.CityId,
       ec.MainCityId
FROM   configflow cf
       INNER JOIN accountids a
       ON cf.mainaccountid = a.mainaccountid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN cityids ec
       ON cf.ExcludeMainCityId = ec.MainCityId;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE ConfigFlow (MainAccountID,IncludeMainCityId,ExcludeMainCityId) AS
SELECT 1100,100,200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1200,200,300 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE AccountIds (AccountId,MainAccountID) AS
SELECT 1,1100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,1100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,1200 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE CityIds (CityId,MainCityId) AS
SELECT 11,100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12,100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13,200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14,300 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



MAINACCOUNTID
INCLUDEMAINCITYID
EXCLUDEMAINCITYID
ACCOUNTID
INCLUDECITYID
INCLUDEMAINCITYID
EXCLUDECITYID
EXCLUDEMAINCITYID




1100
100
200
1
11
100
0
0


1100
100
200
2
11
100
0
0


1100
100
200
1
12
100
0
0


1100
100
200
2
12
100
0
0


1200
200
300
3
13
200
0
0


1100
100
200
1
0
0
13
200


1100
100
200
2
0
0
13
200


1200
200
300
3
0
0
14
300




If you want a single SELECT then you can use UNPIVOT:
SELECT a.*,
       CASE type WHEN 'Include' THEN c.CityId ELSE 0 END AS IncludeCityId,
       CASE type WHEN 'Include' THEN c.MainCityId ELSE 0 END AS IncludeMainCityId,
       CASE type WHEN 'Exclude' THEN c.CityId ELSE 0 END AS ExcludeCityId,
       CASE type WHEN 'Exclude' THEN c.MainCityId ELSE 0 END AS ExcludeMainCityId
FROM   configflow
       UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS(
         MainCityId FOR type IN (
           IncludeMainCityId AS 'Include',
           ExcludeMainCityId AS 'Exclude'
         )
       ) up
       INNER JOIN accountids a
       ON up.MainAccountId = a.MainAccountId
       LEFT OUTER JOIN cityids c
       ON up.MainCityId = c.MainCityId
ORDER BY type DESC, AccountId, IncludeCityId, ExcludeCityId

Which, for the sample data, outputs:



ACCOUNTID
MAINACCOUNTID
INCLUDECITYID
INCLUDEMAINCITYID
EXCLUDECITYID
EXCLUDEMAINCITYID




1
1100
11
100
0
0


1
1100
12
100
0
0


2
1100
11
100
0
0


2
1100
12
100
0
0


3
1200
13
200
0
0


1
1100
0
0
13
200


2
1100
0
0
13
200


3
1200
0
0
14
300



fiddle

What if  ExcludeMainCityId Is null or empty in config flow table ? That means only Inclusion, then ?

@Maria Then use an OUTER JOIN.
